# Passing an array to a Firebird database using Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, blob, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to write to the Firebird 2.5 database a list consisting of: [-0.09143443, 0.09187854, -0.0907896, ...] do everything according to usage guide FDB 1.7:

```
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:/temp/test.db', user='sysdba', password='materkey')

cur = con.cursor()

arrayIn = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9,10,11,12]
  ]

print ('arrayIn:  %s' % (arrayIn))
cur.execute("insert into FACE_REC (ID, ARRAY) values (?, ?)", ('5', arrayIn))

cur.execute("select a from FACE_REC")
arrayOut = cur.fetchone()[0]
print ('arrayOut: %s' % (arrayOut))

con.commit()
```

After that I get an error:

```
TypeError: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

In the database field ARRAY type: BLOB size - 4096, subtype - Text.

Please tell me how to write this list to the database and what type of field should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `blob sub_type text` is not an array datatype, it's a string datatype. You need to convert your array to a suitable string representation before passing it to `execute`. That also means you will need to convert the string representation back to an array on retrieval.

Firebird also has an array datatype, but this is not well supported, but FDB seems to have support for this. If you really want or need to use arrays, you could also try to declare your column as an array type. Given the data shown, you would need to declare the column as `integer[3,4]`, as also shown in the FDB 2.0 documentation, section [Firebird ARRAY datatype](https://fdb.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/usage-guide.html#firebird-array-type):

> ```
> import fdb
>
> con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:/temp/test.db', user='sysdba', password='pass')
> con.execute_immediate("recreate table array_table (a int[3,4])")
> con.commit()
>
> cur = con.cursor()
>
> arrayIn = [
>     [1, 2, 3, 4],
>     [5, 6, 7, 8],
>     [9,10,11,12]
>   ]
>
> print 'arrayIn:  %s' % arrayIn
> cur.execute("insert into array_table values (?)", (arrayIn,))
>
> cur.execute("select a from array_table")
> arrayOut = cur.fetchone()[0]
> print 'arrayOut: %s' % arrayOut
>
> con.commit()
> ```

It looks like you used that code as the base for your code sample, but you seem to have missed the declaration of the column datatype (see the `recreate table` statement near the top).

However, support for arrays in Firebird is very limited, and it might be better to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, I took him for an example, but I did not find the function to "recreate". 
I'll try "pickle.dumps" and "loads", let's see how it works out. Thank you.

Comment: `pickle.dumps` are Python related functionality, that `recreate table` is a Firebird DDL statement. You need to use the right data type in your database, and currently you're not.